# Putting a Dismissible inside of a PageView. Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, wear-os

I want to be able to dismiss a `PageView` when the user swipes right on the leftmost screen.

I tried wrapping the `PageView` in a `Dismissible` widget. Put that causes problems and does not behave as I want it to. It's a bit glitchy.

```dart
Dismissible(
    key: Key("key"),
    direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
    child: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        children: <Widget>[
            FirstPage(),
            SecondPage(),
        ],
    ),
),
```

I've also tried putting a `Dismissible` widget as the first element of the `PageView`'s children. That kind of works. The only thing is that you have to dismiss the `Dismissible` before you can go to the next page. Basically the `Dismissible` blocks swiping to the left to go to the next page in the `PageView`.

```dart
PageView(
    controller: _pageController,
    children: <Widget>[
        Dismissible(
            key: Key("key"),
            direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
            child: FirstPage(),
        ),
        SecondPage(),
    ],
),
```

What can I do to get the expected output, like I described in the beginning.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution? I am in the same situation. It turns out the only way to swipe to the left using PageView is if you use at least to fingers to work.

Comment: @OttoCheley Sadly, I have not :(

Comment: I think the solution for this problem might be using GestureArena, but I'm not quite into it yet. You can read about it here: https://medium.com/koahealth/combining-multiple-gesturedetectors-in-flutter-26d899d008b2